# Is it possible for mongoose to store auto generated MongoId (_id) as string and not ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to know is it possible to store automatically generated mongoId as string which is stored as ObjectId as part of key "_id" of the document while inserting newly into collection?

When we insert document it gets stored as:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("597ece544bdefa24a0a3b20b")
```

can we force MongoDB to store it as:

```
"_id" : "597ece544bdefa24a0a3b20b",
```

Thanks in advance for your views

Comment: Possible? Yes. Advisable. NO. An [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is a **12-byte** value that simply **appears** to be represented as a hexadecimal string. Actually storing as a "sting" requires approximately **26-bytes** including the length and BSON type padding. So more than **twice the size**. You just do not want to do that.

Comment: Good explanation! want to ask one more thing, what could be the best thing done with mongoId in case of aggregation lookup operations. The foreign key scenario of mongodb specially

Comment: If you have a new question then please [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). That is the format here, which is different from a threaded discussion board. Please make sure to search for what you are asking "first" though.

Comment: Its the relative question...As long as aggregation framework concerned, lookup doesn't work if objectId compared with foreign key of itself stored in string format in other collection.

Comment: Well `$lookup` does not match on anything that is not the same [BSON Type](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/bson-types/) for foreign and local **period**. But it's still **not the question you asked** is it. If everything was a "relative question" then most users would simply have **one question** in a near endless thread. But as I stated. **Not the format here**. So if you have a new question about *"trying to match different types using `$lookup`"*, or trying to *"cast types in an aggregation pipeline"* then go ahead and ask it.

Comment: But as a forewarning, both of **those** questions have already been asked, so it would be a duplicate in either case and the answer to both is **You cannot**. Only the "same type" is allowed, and you cannot "re-cast" types.